# Could I execute function right before closure death / garbage collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let me explain what I mean by a simple example:

```
(function(){

    db.queryRows(function(row)
    {
        // some sophisticated async calls could present here
        request.write(row)
    })
    require('some-cool-module').onClosureDeath(function()
    {
        request.end('No more data for you.')
    })

})()
```

Could it be done using domain or some another things? If no, is this theoretically possible?

It seems that I did a bad example, so I wrote another one:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var server = require('http').createServer(function(request, response)
{
    var atEnd = function()
    {
        response.end('No more randoms for you.')
    };

    (function(){    

        response.statusCode = 200;
        response.setHeader('Content-Type','text/html; charset=UTF-8');

        // This loop is emulating a huge sophisticated complex async
        // callback delirium which cannot be easily understood and
        // tracked down, and I won't get paid for its refactoring.
        for(var i = 0;i < getRandomInt(0,getRandomInt(0,1000)); i++)
        {
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                response.write(String(getRandomInt(0,1000) + "<br/>"))
            },getRandomInt(0,30000))
        }

    //  What I'd wish to do:
    //  require('some-cool-module').onClosureDeath(atEnd)

    })()
}
).listen(11111);
console.log("Running @ http://127.0.0.1:11111")
```

Comment: Is there any `on('end'...` in db? I would look at that before trying to pick a module. Also, you can put a callback in your function, that may be cleaner

Comment: The problem I facing right now is equal to no 'end' event in db. I actually don't know where and when will the end come. But it definitely will come right with the end of closure. I thought about using domain somehow, but it has only 'error' event.

Comment: What db library do you use? Also, try with callback, at least you will be able to catch when all request has been sent

Comment: My question is not related to any db. Sure, workaround with callback functions would work, but in code it will look really not nice and not beautiful. That's why I asking this question: I want a better solution than a callback spaghetti.

Answer (score 1):

*(Not a real answer, I just dislike code in comment)*

I don t think something like that would be callback spaghetti

```
function (callback) {
    function atEnd() {
        console.log('No more data');
        callback();
    }

    db.queryRows(function(row)
    {
        // some sophisticated async calls could present here
        request.write(row)
        atEnd();
    })
}
```

EDIT1:
I think you could use something like that (untested!)

```
function callback_hell(callback) //Your callback hell function
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        response.write(String(getRandomInt(0,1000) + "<br/>"));
        callback();
    },getRandomInt(0,30000))
}

function do_all(n, func, callback) { //This is just a wrapper for follow in fact
    var i = 0; //Counter of how many instance of follow have been started

    function follow() { //Wrapper of your callback hell (can be almost anything in fact, I use similar code for downloading files before using them
        if (i < n) { //If there is other instance to run
                callback_hell(follow);//Run it
                i = i + 1; //Increment the counter
        } else { //If all have been made
            console.log('end');
            callback();
        }
    }

    //What must be made before the loop
    response.statusCode = 200;
    response.setHeader('Content-Type','text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    //Start the loop
    follow();
}

do_all(getRandomInt(0, getRandomInt(0, 1000)), callback_hell, function () {
    request.end('No more data for you.');
    console.log('done?');
});
```

Comment: Would you consider another one which I just added?

Comment: You may be able to use something like that, I didn t tested since I don t have node.js on hand, so tell me if it got something wrong.

Comment: As far as I could understand, you suggest me to just wait X seconds to be ensured that callback hell is ended and then do response.end()?

Comment: It seemed like that because I didn t fully adapt the code. What it does is start your callback hell, wait for it to finish, check if it must be run again, if so run it, if not, callback so you can end it. Look at the edit, I (hope definitely this time) rewrite the code for you, it is still untested but should be usable.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating and spending time on my problem, i'll try to apply this approach to my code and see if this could work.

Comment: I'm sorry, but no. I wrote a small async library instead and wrapped every call in it.